# Vue watcher executed before the new data is bound?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using this code:

```
var vueApp = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        modalKanji: {}
    },
    methods: {
        showModalKanji(character) {
            sendAjax('GET', '/api/Dictionary/GetKanji?character=' + character, function (res) { vueApp.modalKanji = JSON.parse(res); });
        }
    },
    watch: {
        'modalKanji': function (newData) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                uglipop({
                    class: 'modalKanji', //styling class for Modal
                    source: 'div',
                    content: 'divModalKanji'
                });
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
});
```

and I have an element that when clicked on, displays a popup with the kanji data inside:

```
<span @click="showModalKanji(kebChar)" style="cursor:pointer;>
    {{kebChar}}
</span>

<div id="divModalKanji" style='display:none;'>
    <div v-if="typeof(modalKanji.Result) !== 'undefined'">
        {{ modalKanji.Result.literal }}
    </div>
</div>
```

It works, but only when used with a setTimeout delay to "let the time for Vue to update its model"...if I remove the setTimeout so the code is called instantaneousely in the watch function, the popup data is always "1 iteration behind", it's showing the info of the previous kanji I clicked...

Is there a way for a watcher function to be called AFTER Vue has completed is binding with the new data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `nextTick`, see [Async-Update-Queue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue)

```
watch: {
    'modalKanji': function (newData) {
        this.$nextTick(function () {
            uglipop({
                class: 'modalKanji', //styling class for Modal
                source: 'div',
                content: 'divModalKanji'
            });
        });
    }
}
```